# How can I use the same ChromeDriver from another method

Tags: c#, selenium

So I have create two methods which I want to use the same ChromDriver. I want the first method to do something with a ChromeDriver and the second method to "continue" the process with the same ChromeDriver.

```
static void FirstDriver()
{
IWebDriver Driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
Driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("login page");
//login to the page
}

static void SecondDriver()
{
IWebDriver Driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
Driver2.Navigate().GoToUrl("login page");
//continue while still loged-in
}
```

I know that an alternative solution would be to get the cookies from Driver1 and use them for Driver2, but I don't know how to do that in selenium...

Comment: *Where* you declare a variable determines its *scope*.  So, when you declare it locally inside a method, thats where it is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Chrome Driver object out of the method so it can be used in multiple places.

Something like this should help get you started.

```
public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    // Both should use the same driver object.
    FirstDriver();
    SecondDriver();
}

static void FirstDriver()
{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("login page");
    //login to the page
}

static void SecondDriver()
{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("login page");
    //continue while still loged-in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the class define driver as global variable and use it

```
**static WebDriver driver;**
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
```